# Python OpenCV Lane Detector "cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.uint8 object" Error

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

i have been trying to use the webcam for the input and its giving me the error.The code was working with pictures.What am i doing wrong

i have tried to set the x1, x2, y1, y2 to integer values and also tried np.array on the make_points function this is the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def detect_edges(frame):
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gry, (5, 5), 0)
    edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150)
    return edges

def region_of_interest(edges):
    height, width = edges.shape
    mask = np.zeros_like(edges)

    polygon = np.array([[
        (0, height * 1 / 2),
        (width, height * 1 / 2),
        (width, height),
        (0, height),
    ]], np.int32)

    cv2.fillPoly(mask, polygon, 255)
    cropped_edges = cv2.bitwise_and(edges, mask)
    return cropped_edges

def detect_line_segments(cropped_edges):
    rho = 1
    angle = np.pi / 180
    min_threshold = 10
    line_segments = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_edges, rho, angle, min_threshold,
                                    np.array([]), minLineLength=8, maxLineGap=4)

    return line_segments

def average_slope_intercept(frame, line_segments):
    lane_lines = []
    if line_segments is None:
        print("No LineSegments!")
    return lane_lines

    height, width, _ = frame.shape
    left_fit = []
    right_fit = []

    boundary = 1/3
    left_region_boundary = width * (1 - boundary)
    right_region_boundary = width * boundary

    for line_segment in line_segments:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line_segment:
            if x1 == x2:
                print("Skipping Vertical Line Segment?")
                continue
            fit = np.polyfit((x1, x2), (y1, y2), 1)
            slope = fit[0]
            intercept = fit[1]
            if slope < 0:
                if x1 < left_region_boundary and x2 < left_region_boundary:
                    left_fit.append((slope, intercept))
            else:
                if x1 > right_region_boundary and x2 > right_region_boundary:
                    right_fit.append((slope, intercept))

    left_fit_average = np.average(left_fit, axis=0)
    if len(left_fit) > 0:
        lane_lines.append(make_points(frame, left_fit_average))

    right_fit_average = np.average(right_fit, axis=0)
    if len(right_fit) > 0:
        lane_lines.append(make_points(frame, right_fit_average))

    print("Lane_Lines :", lane_lines)

    return lane_lines

def make_points(frame, line):
    height, width, _ = frame.shape
    slope, intercept = line
    y1 = height
    y2 = int(y1 * 1 / 2)

    x1 = max(-width, min(2 * width, int((y1 - intercept) / slope)))
    x2 = max(-width, min(2 * width, int((y2 - intercept) / slope)))
    return [[x1, y1, x2, y2]]

def detect_lane(frame):

    edges = detect_edges(frame)
    cropped_edges = region_of_interest(edges)
    line_segments = detect_line_segments(cropped_edges)
    lane_lines = average_slope_intercept(frame, line_segments)

    return lane_lines

def display_lines(frame, lines, line_color=(0, 255, 0), line_width=2):
    line_image = np.zeros_like(frame)
    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                cv2.line(line_image, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), line_color, line_width)
    line_image = cv2.addWeighted(frame, 0.8, line_image, 1, 1)
    return line_image

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video0")

while (cap.isOpened()):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    lane_lines = detect_edges(frame)
    lane_lines_image = display_lines(frame, lane_lines, line_color=(0, 255, 0), line_width=2)
    cv2.imshow("lane lines", lane_lines_image)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        self.cleanup()
    break
```

the cv2.imshow() screen doesnt show up at all and the webcams light just blinks 1 time before spitting out the error

the error is

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/Project-OUTO# python3 WebLane.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WebLane.py", line 108, in <module>
    lane_lines_image = display_lines(frame, lane_lines, line_color=(0, 255, 0), line_width=2)
  File "WebLane.py", line 98, in display_lines
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.uint8 object
```

edit: put print(line) before the for this is what it spits out

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/Project-OUTO# python3 WebLane.py 
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "WebLane.py", line 109, in <module>
    lane_lines_image = display_lines(frame, lane_lines, line_color=(0, 255, 0), line_width=2)
  File "WebLane.py", line 99, in display_lines
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.uint8 object
```

Comment: use `print(line)`  to see what you have in this variable.  Myabe you should do `x1, y1, x2, y2 = line` without `for`.

Comment: i used print line and edited the question with what it spitted out, changing the for to x1, y1, x2, y2 = line got me this : too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Comment: It seems your `line` has something different then you expect. It doesn't have four values `[x1,y1,x2,y2]` nor list with `[ [x1,y1,x2,y2], [x1,y1,x2,y2], [x1,y1,x2,y2],...]`

Comment: you get `line` from `lines` which is created by `lane_lines = detect_edges(frame)` and it seems `detect_edges()` doesn't return coordinates of lines. Maybe it should be different function? maybe it should be `detect_lane` ?

Comment: Ah thank you so much ive been looking at this code for 4 hours straight , i meant to write detect_lane not detect_edges. :D

Answer (score 0):

Resolved thanks to user furas
I had accidentaly written lane_lines = detect_edges()
Meant to be lane_lines = detect_lane()
That fixed the issue for me , Thank you furas :D